# Масштабирование элементов

Tags: android, java

Как сделать чтобы можно было менять масштаб (`scale`) определенного элемента (`view`)? И как определить собственный, пользовательский, способ применения масштаба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых вам нужен GestureListener или любой другой способ задавать размеры (масштабировать) элемент. Затем получив размеры объекта создаётся экземпляр [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) ну и в конце вызываете для нужной вьюхи метод StartAnimation(...)

```
v.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: @alvin, а что за `GestureListener`? Такого класса нет :(

Comment: Думаю, подразумевается `OnScaleGestureListener`.